# What happens to later queries if a previous query has an error

Tags: php, pdo

When I save an array of records i.e multiple records, if one of the records in the middle has an error(sql), what will happen? Will all records henceforth not be inserted or just the current row or none of them? How should I handle the situation?

PDO Driver is Mysql

Comment: What sort of error? And for which RDBMS?

Comment: i mean a sql error say some field/record is null but as per db it shouldn't be

Comment: Mysql stop when begin the first problem (error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution would be to use `TRANSACTION` <sup>[(mysql)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html) [(pgsql)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-transactions.html) [(mssql)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx)</sup>. What you can do with it and how much control you have, depends on RDBMS. For example: PostgreSQL lets you create a `SAVEPOINT`, to which you can `ROLLBACK TO`.

Another solutions would be to use [`STORED PROCEDURE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure). In that case you can can specify what should happen if error occurs with [`DECLARE .. HANDLER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html)

Comment: i want other than the current errorsome query execution to continue... so will that happen

Comment: No, with MySQL's transactions you wont be able to do this. And stored procedure in your case might not be viable. You could always create a prepared statement, and the execute that statement in a loop with new data. The `execute()` method will return `false` if an error happens.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at PDO-Transactions: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

You can check whether there was an error, and if so rollback your commits or do whatever you intend to do

Comment: But, if have a error you need to rollback, so, is like begin another query without transaction, or not?

Comment: i want other than the current errorsome query execution to continue... so will that happen

Answer (score 2):

These situations are managed with [database transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).

The classical example is when I want to transfer money from my account to another account. There are two queries to be done:

1. Remove the money from my account
2. Put the money in the other account

Of course if the second query fails, I want the first one to be rolled back and notify the user of the error. That's what transactions are for.

If you don't use transactions, when the second query fails, the first is executed anyway and not rolled back (so the money disappears). This is the default behaviour of MySQL.

Comment: i want other than the current errorsome query execution to continue... so will that happen